# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ordered' on UpdateView

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

It gives me this error and for the life of me i cannot understand why:

I have a form extended from django-allauth SignupForm...

```
class LearnerSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
```

The form is called in the allauth signup view...

```
class LearnerSignupView(SignupView):
    form_class = LearnerSignupForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:redirect_profile_mixin')
```

The view redirects to a mixin(that extends RedirectView that gets the autheticated user from the request and redirects the connection to an UpdateView passing the parameter user.id..

```
class LearnerUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    formset_Class = LearnerFormSet
    template_name = "formset_edit_learner.html"
    success_url = "home"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LearnerUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        qs = Learner.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        formset = LearnerFormSet(queryset=qs)
        context["learner_formset"] = formset
        return context
```

And then finally to the UpdateView. And it's at this point that i get the error

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ordered'

and

> Exception Location:   C:\Users\aless.virtualenvs\hs_03-LQeWV4ia\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py, line 639, in get_queryset

I know that i'm probably doing something really stupid but i just can't see it. I thank in advance whoever can offer some advice!

Comment: The get_or_create method returns a tuple of (object, created) and this is what you are trying to use as a queryset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As acg said, you're working on a tupple : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

So, without changing your code, you should do :

```py
qs = Learner.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
formset = LearnerFormSet(queryset=qs[0])
```

But that's not very beautiful, you'll better do :

```py
qs, created = Learner.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
formset = LearnerFormSet(queryset=qs)
```